# How to create live search bar, with data from json file?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

### Good day!

So, recently I tried to make my first Single page app. In process, I made some basic template, but then I wanted to add live search functionality.

Basically, you, as a user want to find coworkers info, you use this live search bar to quickly filter through json object, till you find his data.

Thing is, for some reason, I can't get information from json file.

Here is my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hnluR4P9SfwfrQ5STCk)

> Since, to quickly understand my problem you need to see all of my files, I added link to Plunker, but since I need to accompany link with some code, here will be search script, which should get json data, and about.html, where data should be placed in.

**Search.js**

```
$('#search').keydown(function(){
$.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
var search = $('#search').val();
var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
var output;
$.each(data, function(key, val){
if((val.id.search(regex) != -1 ) || (val.name.search(regex) != -1)){
    output += "<tr>";
    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.id+"</td>";
    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.name+"</td>";
    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.email+"</td>";
    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.phone+"</td>";
    output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.city+"</td>";
    output += "</tr>";
  }
});
$('tbody').html(output);
});
})
```

**about.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>About us</h1>
<div class="container" style="padding:50px 250px;">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="search" class="form-control input-lg" id="search" placeholder="Type your search character">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>City</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So, what should happen is, as you write letter, script should print out data from json file, but for some reason, it doesn't.

My question, what is the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly all you need is to use an Angular [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) and off you go, no jQuery needed.

Take a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JafYlUhWh9cVfcP5qbGb?p=preview)

basically you can either assign your `json` to a variable on the `$scope` or use the `$http` service to fetch the data instead like so:

```
simpleApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
   $scope.data = response.data;
  });

});
```

Iterate over it in your view and add a `filter` like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in data | filter:search">
  <td>{{d.id}}</td>
  <td>{{d.name}}</td>
  <td>{{d.email}}</td>
  <td>{{d.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{d.city}}</td>
</tr>
```

add an `ng-model` to your input:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" class="form-control input-lg" id="search" placeholder="Type your search character">
```

And you should be good to go.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for help, but thing is, I would love to get data exactly from json file. I mean, what you did is assign data from file to $scope. But I would love to be able to "assign file" to the $scope. For example, not having to copy+paste data from json file, if I would replace it. Sorry if I am asking something stupid, I am still just amatour.

Comment: Fair enough, to get data from json file (or other source) you can use `$http` service. See updated answer.

Comment: Hey, I just found article where my own question was answered. Ty very much for your time. :)

Comment: In any case I'd suggest you ditch `JQuery` and let Angular built in services do the heavy lifting for you. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular-bootstrap typeahead to achieve this.
The example here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

The typeahead can be used only in an array. so apply a filter. That's it